# why image is not displayed in UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[currentPhoto fileName]];
NSLog(@"%@",[currentPhoto fileName]);
[self.currentImage setImage:image];
```

its displays the correct image name in debug area 
which i want to display on UIImageView. currentImage is outlet hooked in .h file

Is it because of new Auto-layout feater of iOS 6 i am not getting it.
It used to work in iOS 5.

My purpose is to display image in an UIImageView on a particular Scene

I have also tried to set Default image which i have copied in my project folder.
But i am getting an error debug area as follows:

```
Could not load the "myImage.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.xxx.xxx"
```

Comment: Is it working in simulator? Also try setting a frame for self.currentImage and check.

Comment: On Simulator its not working and i have not tried on Device yet...shall i do that....

Comment: I am still stucked with same problem.Now i am not able to load even default image.

Comment: Are you sure that the image is not corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that image name carries the extension(.jpg/.png) as well. Also have you defined an iBoutlet for the imageView??

Also if the problem is with autolayout,you can disable it in the Xib. Learn it from here.
http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/

Comment: Yes i am using an extension .png for my image.. and i have disabled auto-layout as well...but its still not working

Comment: I am still stucked with same problem.Now i am not able to load even default image.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to File-->Add Files "ProjectName"
Below windows pops up.

And Default option selected by Xcode was 
"Create folder references for any added folders" as shown pic below
which was producing 

**Error(in Debug area) :**

    `Could not load the "myImage.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.xxx.xxx"`

[image: Wrong options selected]

**Solution to above Problem :** 

Select "Create groups for any added folders" which Xcode generally select was not the case this time.

[image]

Solution is so simple but sometimes silly mistakes happens.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is not added to the project, it wont be available for imageNamed call.To load the image which is not added to the project use this call

`UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgFilePath];`